# Xamarin Designer throws exception

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I'm working on a current project using Xamarin.Android. I got several view sthat use the same layout. I got used to define everything in a style for this while working with Android Studio. The problem is that Xamarin's Designer doesn't accept that "layout_width" and "layout_height" are defined in a style.

Of course it is a possibility to define those with the views, but it would increase the lines of XML-code quite a bit, and also I'd have to change more than one view if I'd change something.

I already looked into the topic but didn't find a workaround. Maybe someone got a similar problem and might have found a proper solution.

**Fragment_Therapist.axml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:weightSum="7">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ImageView
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:id="@+id/profile_icon"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    <!-- Profile Name -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/sublayout_I"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/profile_icon">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/profile"
                android:text="@string/therapistfragment_profile"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:minWidth="50dp"
                android:textSize="25dp" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/profile_name"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    <!-- Profile Description-->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/sublayout_II"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/sublayout_I">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/description"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:minWidth="50dp"
                android:text="@string/therapistfragment_description"
                android:textSize="25dp" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/profile_description"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
<!-- Edit, Info, Delete, Cancel and Save-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="2">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:weightSum="2">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1">
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/edit"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />
            </RelativeLayout>
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1">
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/info"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:weightSum="4">
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/left"
                style="@style/PlaceHolder" />
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2">
                <Button
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />
            </RelativeLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/right"
                style="@style/PlaceHolder" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**styles.xml**

```xml
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <resources>
      <style name="PlaceHolder">
        <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
      </style>        
  </resources>
```

Comment: Please share content of your XMLs

Comment: Right, please add your layout code

Comment: `<LinearLayout
   style="@style/PlaceHolder" />`

`<style name="PlaceHolder">
    <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
  </style>` @OrkhanAlikhanov @olegflo

Comment: @TheFrozenDuck [Edit] your post and include entire content of xml codes if possible

Comment: @OrkhanAlikhanov done